# JavaFX how to change scene within a runnable

Tags: java, javafx

I'm having an app which enables a customer to place an order for a ride (as in Uber), initially considered in a "WAITING" phase. When a driver accepts the order, it is automatically set in an "ACCEPTED" phase.

When ACCEPTED, the user is going to be redirected to another scene, telling him that he needs to wait for his rider to pick him up.

I decided to create a thread that checks every 250ms if the status of his order was set to ACCEPTED, like that:

```
public class AcceptanceRunnable implements Runnable {

    private boolean running;

    public AcceptanceRunnable() {
        running = true;
    }

    public void run() {
        do {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(250);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (OrderService.checkIfAccepted(OrderSession.getOrder())) {
                // move to other scene
                break;
            }
        } while(running);
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
    }
}
```

This `AcceptanceRunnable` class gets instantiated within the controller in the `initialize()` method:

```
@FXML
public void initialize() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    sourceAddress.setText("From: " + OrderSession.getOrder().getSourceAddress());
    destinationAddress.setText("To: " + OrderSession.getOrder().getDestinationAddress());
    price.setText("You'll need to pay RON " + 
    UserService.calculatePrice(UserSession.getUser()) + " for this ride.");

    acceptanceRunnable = new AcceptanceRunnable();
    Thread t = new Thread(acceptanceRunnable);
    t.start();
}
```

Everything works fine. If I just print out some lines while waiting for the order's status to get changed, it seems to be okay. The problem is, I want my user to be redirected to another scene, if his order gets accepted.

This means, I need to insert something in place of the comment made in my `AcceptanceRunnable.run()` method.

I also tried changing the scene by having a method called `ifAccepted()` inside my controller, which actually triggers the method that changes the scene:

```
if (OrderService.checkIfAccepted(OrderSession.getOrder())) {
    try {
        Class<?> controller = Class.forName("com.example.yuber.controllers.CustomerWaitController");
        Method ifAccepted = controller.getMethod("ifAccepted");
        ifAccepted.invoke(controller.newInstance());
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    break;
}
```

But I only get some `NullPointerException` and I'm pretty sure that what I do here isn't really correct.

Any opinions?

Comment: Side note: Assuming `setRunning` is invoked by a different thread than the one that invokes `run`, then the `running` variable needs to be `volatile` (or some other concurrency solution needs to be used).

Comment: You're calling `ifAccepted()` on a new controller instance (and why are you using reflection here? that seems unnecessarily complex). That won't have any FXML fields injected, because it wasn't managed by an `FXMLLoader` (assuming we're talking about FXML controllers here). You need a reference to the controller "linked" with the UI and then run the UI-updating code using `Platform#runLater(Runnable)`, or use a `javafx.concurrent.Task` and set `Task#setOnSucceeded(EventHandler)` or override `Task#succeeded()` method.

Comment: Though it may make more sense to use a `javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService`.

Answer (score 0):

As [Slaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6395627/slaw) suggested, using `Platform#runLater(Runnable)` fixed my problem.

What I actually did was add my `run()` method from the Runnable inside my controller, renaming it to `handleTread()`:

```
public void handleThread() {
    do {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(250);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (OrderService.checkIfAccepted(OrderSession.getOrder())) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
            try {
                SceneService.NewScene("/com/example/yuber/accepted-view.fxml", (Stage) rootPane.getScene().getWindow(), rootPane.getScene());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            break;
        }
    } while(running);
}
```

Not using `Platform.runLater(...)` would result in receiving a `Not on FX Application Thread` error.

Everything seems to be fine now.